# Pig not locating Hive Table using Hcatalog

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I using PIG to access a table batting_data created via HCatalog. While doing so I am facing an error saying the mentioned table was not not found. However this batting_data table is available in HIVE. I also understand that if the database name is not mentioned then default is assumed.

**ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1115: Table not found : default.batting_data table not found**

1. I have setup hive-site.xml as below. Pls note am not using a remote server for the metastore but a local server which is mysql

   ```
   <configuration>
   <property>
           <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
           <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
           <description>the URL of the MySQL database</description>
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
           <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
           <value>root</value>
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
           <value>root</value>
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>hive.hwi.listen.host</name>
           <value>0.0.0.0</value>
   </property>
   <property>
           <name>hive.hwi.listen.port</name>
           <value>9999</value>
   </property>
   <property>
           <name>hive.hwi.war.file</name>
           <value>lib/hive-hwi-0.12.0.war</value>
   </property>

   <property>
           <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
           <value>true</value>
   </property>
   ```
2. I have setup the below in my .bashrc for the PIG integration with HIVE and HCATALOG.

   export PIG_OPTS=-Dhive.metastore.local=true
   export PIG_CLASSPATH=$HCAT_HOME/share/hcatalog/*:$HIVE_HOME/lib/*
3. The below statement will be loaded by default when the GRUNT shell when PIG starts.

   REGISTER /home/shiva/hive-0.12.0/hcatalog/share/hcatalog/hcatalog-core-0.12.0.jar;
   REGISTER /home/shiva/hive-0.12.0/lib/hive-exec-0.12.0.jar;
   REGISTER /home/shiva/hive-0.12.0/lib/hive-metastore-0.12.0.jar;

---

The complete log of the error message is below. Any help in fixing this would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
grunt> a = LOAD 'batting_data' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();         
2015-01-01 01:06:33,849 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: Opening raw store with implemenation class:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore
2015-01-01 01:06:33,865 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore - ObjectStore, initialize called
2015-01-01 01:06:34,049 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Persistence - Property datanucleus.cache.level2 unknown - will be ignored
2015-01-01 01:06:34,365 [main] WARN  com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig - Max Connections < 1. Setting to 20
2015-01-01 01:06:35,470 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore - Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
2015-01-01 01:06:35,501 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore - Initialized ObjectStore
2015-01-01 01:06:36,265 [main] WARN  com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPConfig - Max Connections < 1. Setting to 20
2015-01-01 01:06:36,506 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_database: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck
2015-01-01 01:06:36,506 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit - ugi=shiva   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_database: NonExistentDatabaseUsedForHealthCheck 
2015-01-01 01:06:36,512 [main] ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler - NoSuchObjectException(message:There is no database named nonexistentdatabaseusedforhealthcheck)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getMDatabase(ObjectStore.java:431)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDatabase(ObjectStore.java:441)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingRawStore.invoke(RetryingRawStore.java:124)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6.getDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.get_database(HiveMetaStore.java:628)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.get_database(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.getDatabase(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:810)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.isOpen(HiveClientCache.java:277)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:147)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:547)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.getHiveMetaClient(PigHCatUtil.java:150)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.PigHCatUtil.getTable(PigHCatUtil.java:186)
    at org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader.getSchema(HCatLoader.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:175)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.<init>(LOLoad.java:89)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:853)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:3479)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1536)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1013)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:553)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:188)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1648)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1621)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:575)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1093)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:501)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:198)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:173)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:541)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:156)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)

2015-01-01 01:06:36,514 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore - 0: get_table : db=default tbl=batting_data
2015-01-01 01:06:36,514 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.audit - ugi=shiva   ip=unknown-ip-addr  cmd=get_table : db=default tbl=batting_data 
2015-01-01 01:06:36,516 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Datastore - The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
2015-01-01 01:06:36,516 [main] INFO  DataNucleus.Datastore - The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
2015-01-01 01:06:36,795 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1115: Table not found : default.batting_data table not found
Details at logfile: /home/shiva/pig_1420054544179.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here goes.. I fixed it..

1. I had not mentioned the PIG_OPTS with the correct address of the HIVE THRIFT server due to which PIG was not able to connect to HIVE metastore and therefoer table not found. 
   Changed it to `PIG_OPTS=-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:10000`
2. Start the HIVESERVER service using

   $ bin/hive --service hiveserver

The above fixed the issue and now am able to connect PIG to HIVE.
Thanks